# TypeScript error expects only a single key of object instead of full

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {useState} from 'react';

type Configs = {
  mysql: {
      datasourceName: string;
      host: string;
      port: string;
      databaseName: string;
      username: string;
      password: string;
    },
  mongodb: {
      accessKeyId: string;
      secretAccessKey: string;
      region: string;
      datasourceName: string;
    }
}

async function updateMysql({config}: {config: Configs['mysql']}) {}

async function updateMongo({config}: {config: Configs['mongodb'] }) {}

const datasources = [
  {
    type: "mongodb",
    caller: updateMongo,
    form: MongoForm,
    default: {
      accessKeyId: "",
      secretAccessKey: "",
      region: "",
      datasourceName: "",
    },
  },
  {
    type: "mysql",
    caller: updateMysql,
    form: MySQLForm,
    default: {
      datasourceName: "",
      host: "",
      port: "",
      databaseName: "",
      username: "",
      password: "",
      workspaceId: "",
    },
  },
] as const;
type FormType = React.ComponentType<{
  data: Configs[keyof Configs];
  setData: (
    path: keyof Configs[keyof Configs],
    value: string
  ) => void;
}>;
function DatabaseModal({dbType}: {dbType: keyof Configs}){
    const datasource = datasources.find(({type}) => type === dbType)!;
    const [config, setConfig] = useState(datasource.default);
    const handleDataChange = (
    k: keyof Configs[keyof Configs],
    value: string
    ) => {
        // ...
    };
    async function handleSave(dbType: keyof Configs) {
        if (datasource.type === 'mongodb'){
            await datasource.caller({
                config: config as Configs['mongodb'],
            });
        } else {
            await datasource.caller({
                config:  config as Configs['mysql'],
            });
        }    
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <datasource.form data={config} setData={handleDataChange} /> // <--- error her
        </div>
    )
}

type FormProps = {
  data: Configs[keyof Configs];
  setData: (
    path: keyof Configs[keyof Configs],
    value: string
  ) => void;
}

function MongoForm(props: FormProps) {
    const region = props.setData('region', 'some region');
    return <form></form>
}

function MySQLForm(props: FormProps) {
    const host = props.setData('host', 'some host');
    return <form></form>
}
```

How would I fix this? the playground can be found here: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoUSWOAbwFcBnJAZRhRiQF85tcCi6GGXLkYATzBI4AYQgA7TMADmjOAF465OHBDjGARwA2ALi06LcACYcUjCPShokAORQgkZxjCjB5yiksdAAsIby8fPwDtIOoYCN9-QKCbdgAjO1d3TzhvROiguCYkKHlshKjkyzA7RgB3aCsKpJidLgAaGJAFZQgrNLNaVot0Z0ZGAGkkcQBJJtzIlsLmNCIYAEE0Mcnp5oKgomVgBT2qi1S7Bycsj1PhrnIHsUlpGRQjIxK1TSGdAG0JnA-HAANbTCCYWQKJSqAC6ZgAFL8LGhoSpOm1BsNUYoVGY5LjVADYTEuABKDQAPjgADcIMArI9RDjvHA0O9PlBGPiOV8NOZdPpjIjaDiYVxBmK8VDCYw-vg9IYjPhYeSqXQOl0en0BnAkVLlBK6Ab8WiiQrtf0VWr1NTaJqnnZxPI0Lx6C6YMd5EUwKkkABZIVGfVmo2is2m2XyxXGa0U+2iJ0ut0er0+v3+7Uhwlhk0ymFyi3+HUquBqhPkFnwC72Rxjfl-GLInQSKRmABE3WL-XbGIsw0w0BAZkzxYAYkO+zorEhMCh6EZ4gLLKMkOMprN5u3e8MdCs1ptthuOzvCocvSep+dbLXrm5bnBt1fNW0+824K2cp2g6eLIOoMOcCBiwACKAAyE4AVeM5zguS7vtON5XM495fr+lihOEj7oRYcSXru1i2BkzCofhhTFKU5TYVeOg1OMDRQFuOE6AxIKMDUzhzGRFgvmWnSwnAdhsgo3gUOQmDuhgaYACJEZkmY2MGtD9AAKi8YaqS8ZhguIEL5iojDku+VaEewt7OPyNbIWuAB0SjyFYCJIp+NrUp+GjqJomlSGSACEZwmX8BrtLkSAwASMICZoxRsBwSAIlZdZIDZMHzouZIBSJ8DBCgDmfLJ7AyDl-jSJoCLDCC2ngpCEUGX8Ol6bVcJXjS7z0DkeRRMMFK2suQQAPT9XANkjfcZxJq6EmpgocDFVYnwsCgNLxd5OQNTVZqMPGBE6MAkIJUhSU2e5nmaEWvRWmSCGFIJdQoMA8Dsh8XzRpaaQqkiO03ToeYGoJahNYWXYXe9sI0Td5JnJYPBIEYzB9d9KB3Q9bK8ly0ZBh913fT9Ea44S-36eaMbKmDX3QxlX08P20OiJYayON65XfQAPFYwA0pS5MWGzh3XHZQ6mSg6jhjmoUwAVwu0HN+W2EVuXKNwcD9VzrP9eznPdUyzxSHAkEgAACjgYDfAKFyRgW9XVUTjCwskzAS7YiLDDUMDBFVukbVG6022TlitUY7V7DEPXUnSDIUE8U1STNo69PrCJgMb3J60ORsQCb22WCZ54zZoScZ4wNkO5LCKEEgRwKPgIX4PYHhwLn8j4JT9NhYzcAs-+ICUiz-Vd1zUeSZ6sfiKBEFDonydmPr6eZ31JmYfA+fJ8XYWl-gi-VwQdfSJvLcWAzpQd-3vf99rQA)

Comment: Do you want to tag this with “react” if the question depends on it? Or remove the references to react if it doesn’t ?

Comment: @reactor I don't see any error [here](https://tsplay.dev/wjak8W). Please provide some playground with the error occurring

Comment: @reactor Is it okay if we change the structure of `datasources` to an object where the keys are `mysql`, `mongodb` and the values are their configuration?

Comment: @wonderflame definitely. I'm open to any restructuring and other incidental improvements

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generic type to achieve it. Refer this [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoUSWOAbwFcBnJAZRhRiQF85tcCi6GGXLkYATzBI4AYQgA7TMADmjOAF465OHBDjGARwA2ALi06LcACYcUjCPShokAORQgkZxjCjB5yiksdAAsIby8fPwDtIOoYCN9-QKCbdgAjO1d3TzhvROiguCYkKHlshKjkyzA7RgB3aCsKpJidLgAaGJAFZQgrNLNaVot0Z0ZGAGkkcQBJJtzIlsLmNCIYAEE0Mcnp5oKgomVgBT2qi1S7Bycsj1PhrnIH8gB6Z7hV1E4rOBQ4ZSR5CVgGg4BIpGJJNIpvoAPKYaGMAA8ABUAHwaOhwADaAAU4H44ABraYQTBwZEAXTMyNxFLgSAAHpx5FY1BA0gArJAYOAAfiJJLJNJxdOptLgXCxxPEpPJFNEYOkMhQRiMJTUmiGOixE3x8gFMrJckUKkYVLgAAotRY0AolMpOm1BsNbSblGZjfbGDr5W0AJQadEANwgwCsj1Eru87xVaqgjA9sfVGOtekMpkttFd9q4g2zKg9dtNWPwaeM%20ApXAD6nRtA6XR6fQGmfzylzdFbhbd3tLjf6Fargbo9aednE8hBmHoE5gx319DAqSQAFl9MYra321mi%207ZDue2WjAOA3XRGOJ7xpxg50VFxwV42Nzut52992S91-E2KxKT08o-AFz2I4YwYliMTWjoipmAARJ%20vT9DBjoWMMmDQCAZjLo2ABi6HIToVhIJgKD0EY8TmEEoxIOM0JzLBSHDDoKxrJs2zQvR%20EWIcc4cYx1i2MB1xuLccAwQxlj1m0yGQaCkKwYe4kWGhUAYXAq4sAAigAMrhKmcYRxGkeRMkEQJVzOMJORiZxIRhOR1l8XEvGFBcGTMJZzlBMUpTlKJinVLUDRQPMDmFEFhKMDUzh0X5nGSRKnR0nY7wKN4FDkFOM43gAIrYbkPjYRhWv0yKQluJVyQasqeqaVYyQB-HsIJzgYkB5nUQAdEoLIWlaiqDjWslSBo6iaBVUh%20gAhGcDVYq27S5EgMA1codKaMUbD3habUgUgHUGSRZF%20jNqXwMEKAsmquXsDI53%20NImgWsMhJmAicIIoiK2MKinFBiq9A5HkUTDNWtZ8TorxwB10P3Gc56Tles4KHAd1WGqLAoEGSDbWkpVSGY0rVfuJ7g-iZLbWZu0dYqI2aL2X79n6JmFD8dQoMA8BoEm8Yfn2aQVlapMsylbpmK2PxqF9vMM-zFI2SzVZnBJ9JGMwFHCzoKBsxzMaquqH5rkeFKCxrLOviL9oS2%20XoG%20mFby4UiukzwKESaIlhrI4%20pPcLiJWMAQaokLFh%205T1xdehjUoOo25ujwzAwNd0e0KjV22LdF3-DwzxB77zz%204HIMRhCw26SAOI4GAGoURcXY24TRr7hSyQJ0nZg%20xYNQwMEr3TIw71959%204-cMf1GADewxKDcAhmGFBPJl17I1hX5lxaYCVwmcBlxXEBVyTlgNdxyOaBve%20MB1re2BahBIEcCj4At%20D2B4cDH-I%20DHcMnulHAiLKSAVEiJngAKDgvRGN51LaTXmfKuZgd6bwPjaU6KM7IYlgRfK%207Ab6hG8I-AgL9pC4OEF-D2S0vZ-1AcA0BxdyBAA)

This is what I have added:

```
// created a generic type
type KeysOfKeys<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends object ? keyof T[P] : T[P] }[keyof T]
```

This will give all the keys of the inner objects.

And replaced both `keyof Configs[keyof Configs]` with `KeysOfKeys<Configs>`

Now this should accept all keys of the inner object.

And if you want the keys of inner object along with outer object, you can do this:

```
type KeysOfKeys<T> = keyof T | { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends object ? keyof T[P] : T[P] }[keyof T]
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is about having an error when trying to pass the props. Even if we apply your type to the code it will still have the same error

Comment: The error is showing because when using `keyof Configs[keyof Configs]` as type for the prop: 'path', This type will allow only the common keys in the inner object of the 'Configs'. So Changing the type for that prop is the way to solve the error in your playground link. From what I have understood, if you think this is not you want, please explain your issue details so I can help you any further with your issue.

Comment: This is not my question. Your approach allows to send any data and set any value even if it is not related to the given database